# PHP SimpleXML Get Value

Tags: php, xpath, simplexml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<languages>
    <language lan="de">
        <lanString key="siteTitle">Simple engine DE</lanString>
    </language>
    <language lan="en">
        <lanString key="siteTitle">Simple engine EN</lanString>
        <lanString key="welcomeText">Welcome to Simple engine</lanString>
    </language>
</languages>
```

How can i access the value of lanString with the key: "siteTitle"
I have tried it with the following:

```
public function getString($key, $lan){
    return $this->mXmlFile->xpath('language[@lan="'.$lan.'"]/lanString[@key="'.$key.'"]');
}
```

But there is no output :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code, using the same XML that you provided and the same call to xpath(), works well:

```
function getString($xml, $key, $lan){
  return $xml->xpath('language[@lan="'.$lan.'"]/lanString[@key="'.$key.'"]');
}

$data = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <languages>
    <language lan="de">
      <lanString key="siteTitle">Simple engine DE</lanString>
  </language>
  <language lan="en">
      <lanString key="siteTitle">Simple engine EN</lanString>
      <lanString key="welcomeText">Welcome to Simple engine</lanString>
  </language>
</languages>';

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($data);

print_r(getString($xml, "siteTitle", "de"));
```

For the sake of simplicity, I changed the method into a simple function. It prints out:

```
Array
(
    [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [@attributes] => Array
                (
                    [key] => siteTitle
                )

            [0] => Simple engine DE
        )
)
```

So I think the code that you provided is OK. If it doesn't show any output, the issue might be somewhere else...